# function find() with variable as a parameter returns empty object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm refactoring a code on a generated web page and there is a div (tab) which can occur multiple times. There is a small section with check-boxes on each and every such div, which lets you choose other divs that will be shown.

Since there is a chance for other divs to be added to the page I wanted to make the code modular. Meaning that every checkbox `id` is identical to the `class` of the div, which it should toggle, with added "Div" at the end. So I use checked `id`, concat it with *"."* and *"Div"* and try to find it in closest fieldset.

Here is the almost working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ebwokLpf/5/ (I can't find the way to make the onchange work)

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".inChecks").each(function(){
      changeDivState($(this));
  });
});

function changeDivState(element){
  var divClassSel = "." + element.attr("id") + "Div";
  var cloField = element.closest("fieldset");
  if(element.prop("checked")){
      cloField.find(divClassSel).toggle(true);
  } else {
      cloField.find(divClassSel).toggle(false);
  }
}
```

Aside for that not-working onchange, this functionality does what it's intended to do. However only on the jsfiddle. The same code does not work on my page.

When I used log on variables from the code, the result was as this

```
console.log(divClassSel)    => inRedDiv
console.log($(divClassSel)) => Object[div.etc.]
console.log(cloField)       => Object[fieldset.etc.]
//but
console.log(cloField.find(divClassSel)) => Object[]
```

According to firebug the version of the jQuery is 1.7.1

Since I can't find any solution to this is there any other way how to make it in modular manner? Or is there some mistake I'm not aware of? I'm trying to avoid writing a function with x checks for element id, or unique functions for every check-box (the way it was done before).

Comment: For the `change` binding issue use jQuery  `$(":checkbox").on("change", function() { // 'this' will be the element })`. Attributes for event binding are to be avoided when possible.

Comment: thanks, fiddle updated

Comment: Also you can simplify this `if(element.prop("checked")){
        cloField.find(divClassSel).toggle(true);
    } else {
        cloField.find(divClassSel).toggle(false);
    }` by just `cloField.find(divClassSel).toggle(element.prop("checked"));`

Comment: this is nice, but i still need to do some actions after toggling the section so the if/else has its meaning.

Comment: Check two things: 1. Ensure `divClassSel` has a dot as first char (in the logs you posted it has not); 2. Look in `cloField.html()` if there is really an element with class `divClassSel` inside.

Comment: The problem was in the way the application generated the HTML. Using a form object (application's own entity) as a fieldset child led to its separation a it was placed outside it. (No idea why). So I wrapped the fieledset and form objects in another div. Now I search for closest div with CSS class and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline `onchange` and also you don't need to iterate on the elements.

Just write one event on class **"inCheckes"** and pass the current element reference to your function:

### HTML:

```
<fieldset id="field1">
    <legend>Fieldset 1</legend>
    <table class="gridtable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="inRed" class="inChecks" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
            </td>
            <td>Red</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="inBlue" class="inChecks" type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td>Blue</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="inDivs">
        <div class="inRedDiv redDiv"></div>
        <div class="inBlueDiv blueDiv" /></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="field2">
    <legend>Fieldset 2</legend>
    <table class="gridtable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="inRed" class="inChecks" type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td>Red</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="inBlue" class="inChecks" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
            </td>
            <td>Blue</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="inDivs">
        <div class="inRedDiv redDiv"></div>
        <div class="inBlueDiv blueDiv" /></div>
</fieldset>
```

### JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".inChecks").change(function () {
        changeDivState($(this));
    })
});
```

### FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/ebwokLpf/4/

Comment: That's a problem in the code but I think the real question is about `find`

Comment: right, I have no problem with onchange (it wasn't working on jsfiddle). The problem is, that somehow the find() returns empty object

Comment: And this iteration trough every element is here because some values might be pre-filled from application.

Answer (score 0):

As gillesc said in the comments changing the javascript code to something like this made it work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inChecks").each(function(){
        changeDivState($(this));
    });

    $(".inChecks").on("change", function() {
        changeDivState($(this));
    });
});

function changeDivState(element){
    var divClassSel = "." + element.attr("id") + "Div";
    var cloField = element.closest("fieldset");
    if(element.prop("checked")){
        cloField.find(divClassSel).toggle(true);
    } else {
        cloField.find(divClassSel).toggle(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for an other way how to make it in modular manner:

You can create a **jQuery plugin which handles the logic for one fieldset** including changing the color when clicking different checkboxes.
This way all **logic is bundled in one place** (in the plugin) and you can **refine it later on**.
For example you can decide later on that the plugin should create the whole html structure of the fieldset (like jQuery UI slider plugin creates the whole structure for the slider element) and therefore change the plugin.

The code for the (first version) of your jQuery plugin could look something like this:

```
$.fn.colorField = function() {
    var $colorDiv = this.find('.colorDiv'),
        $inputs = this.find('input'),
        $checked = $inputs.filter(':checked');

    if($checked.length) {
        // set initial color
        $colorDiv.css('background', $checked.attr('data-color'));
    }

    $inputs.change(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            background = '#999'; // the default color

        if($this.prop('checked')) {
            // uncheck the other checkboxes
            $inputs.not(this).prop('checked', false);
            // read the color for this checkbox
            background = $(this).attr('data-color');
        }
        // change the color of the colorDiv container
        $colorDiv.css('background', background);
    });
};
```

The plugin uses the `data-color`-attributes of the checkboxes to change the color of the `colorDiv` container. So every checkbox needs an `data-color` attribute, but **multiple divs for different colors are not necessary anymore**.

The HTML code (for one fieldset):

```
<fieldset id="field1">
    <legend>Fieldset 1</legend>
    <table class="gridtable">
        <tr><td><input id="inRed" class="inChecks" type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-color='#ff1005' /></td><td>Red</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input id="inBlue" class="inChecks" type="checkbox" data-color='#00adff' /></td><td>Blue</td></tr>
    </table>
    <div class="colorDiv"></div>
</fieldset>
```

Now you can **create instances with your `colorField`-plugin** like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#field1').colorField();
    $('#field2').colorField();
});
```

Here is a working **[jsFiddle-demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ebwokLpf/10/)**

Comment: @Gagan Thank you. I changed the link.